# Querying Firebase based on time

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am trying to query my Firebase based on time limits. I am following [this blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html) with this attached [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/EZUtP/).

The issue is that I am getting a blank firebaseArray back.

```
        var currentTime = (new Date).getTime();
        var twentyFoursHoursAgo = currentTime - 86400000;

        //scoresRef is defined as new Firebase(http://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/scores)
        scoresRef.on('value', function (dataSnapshot) {
        var summaryScores = $firebaseArray(scoresRef.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(twentyFoursHoursAgo).endAt(currentTime));
        $scope.summaryScores = summaryScores;
        console.log(summaryScores);
        }
```

The idea is that as users add more scores, the array will change. Then I can do different data manipulation on it (like average, etc). That way, there can be a running 24 hour average displayed on the app.

This is what the data looks like in Firebase:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I know the data is in there.

Comment: The property containing the timestamp is called `timestamp` so: `Ref.child("timestamp").startAt(twentyFoursHoursAgo).endAt(currentTime)`

Comment: I don't think that would work. See their guide here: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html. It looks like you want the parent node.

Comment: That  blog post is very old, by Firebase standards. You'll be better off reading the **current** documentation, i.e. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries or even just a newer blog post: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-11-04-firebase-realtime-queries.html. But aside from that: `Ref.child("scores").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(twentyFoursHoursAgo).endAt(currentTime)`. If you set up a fiddle with your own data and code in it, I'll look further.

Comment: I edited my post with your suggestion and links. The adding of `orderByChild` is still not giving the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this answer your question, but it seems the best I can do is show you something that works.

### Querying for a range of timestamps

I added this data structure:

```
{
    "-Jy5pXbn5RpiK1-5z07O": {
        "timestamp": 1441076226561
    },
    "-Jy5pZJsYvsmv_dMtCtn": {
        "timestamp": 1441076173543
    },
    "-Jy5paWbkU6F8C6CEGpj": {
        "timestamp": 1441076181550
    },
    "-Jy5pbc0pJ1I5azenAi5": {
        "timestamp": 1441076247056
    },
    "-Jy5pfnMDKExW2oPf-D-": {
        "timestamp": 1441076204166
    },
    "-Jy5pgk55ypuG9_xICq-": {
        "timestamp": 1441076268053
    },
    "-Jy5phVgU2hDE_izcR8p": {
        "timestamp": 1441076271163
    },
    "-Jy5pilBteGhu05eMWQI": {
        "timestamp": 1441076215315
    }
}
```

And then query with this code:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/32321406');

var startAt = 1441076265715;
var endAt = startAt + 15000;

var query = ref.orderByChild('timestamp')
               .startAt(startAt)
               .endAt(endAt);
query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Which outputs:

```
{
  -Jy5pgk55ypuG9_xICq-: {
    timestamp: 1441076268053
  },
  -Jy5phVgU2hDE_izcR8p: {
    timestamp: 1441076271163
  }
}
```

And a warning that I should add an indexing rule for `timestamp`.

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/qaxosisuha/edit?js,console

### Binding a collection of data from Firebase to AngularJS

If you're trying to bind the query results to an AngularJS view, you do this by:

```
$scope.items = $firebaseArray(query);
```

When using AngularFire **don't** try to use `console.log` to monitor what is going in. Instead add this to your HTML:

```
<pre>{{ items | json }}</pre>
```

This will print the items and automatically update as the data is asynchronously loaded and updated.

Note that this may be a good time to go through Firebase's [AngularFire programming guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/), which explains [this last bit](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro) and many more topics in a pretty easy to follow manner.